# I've tried to improve a question, can you check it?

Tags: support, specific-question

I would like to ask for a favor. I've tried to improve a question, can you have a look to it?

[What is catcomplete in jQuery's autocomplete plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655534/js-and-jquery-syntax-understanding-a-real-example)

Comment: On all that text in your question I can't tell what your single question is? When asking keep it short: Problem, current code, 1 question.

Comment: 17 downvotes seems a bit harsh - although I bet there is a history behind that. Either way, as Juergen says, it's very hard to parse a question from the text, that would be the most obvious candidate for fixing.

Comment: 20 down votes.... it's not _that_ bad in it's current form... I guess that's why you're here seeing as you have an answer?

Comment: Tanner/Pekka, See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275810/1110381 for why the question is heavily downvoted. @OP, You have a list with 7 individual points, each containing one or more questions - that's about 6 too many. Furthermore, not only does that list partially repeat itself (2 questions essentially asking "what is catcomplete"), it also contains useless questions like "who named this" - as demonstrated by the answer, this leads to useless answers. Your english (_what_, not _who_ is catcomplete, etc, etc) also makes things worse. All in all, your question still feels like a mess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few issues with your 'question'.  Here's what you can do to make it better:

**The Title**: Arguably the most important part of your question. Your title should convey what a user who has your problem would search for.  Your title should be specific enough to cover the programming concept you have a problem with, and general enough to be useful to other people.  This is a fine line to walk.

On the front page I've found the following Good and poor question titles, all recast as Thanksgiving cooking questions (in the spirit of Thanksgiving)

Good question titles:

- [Flying Effect in HTML using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735256/flying-effect-in-html-using-jquery) (Deepfrying turkey in deep fryer using Canola oil)
- [Datetime Parse with cultureinfo on Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678899/datetime-parse-with-cultureinfo-on-windows-server-2012) (My oven burns turkey when using butter)
- [How to declare a type being a list of entries in Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734611/how-to-declare-a-type-being-a-list-of-entries-in-swagger) (How do I get a brown exterior to my turkey when using a shallow baking dish?)

Poor question titles:

- [Rasbian Java and gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735739/rasbian-java-and-gstreamer) (Turkey, Barbecue Sauce, and Dutch oven)
- [Using button to retrieve data in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734810/using-button-to-retreive-data-from-xml) (Using Hammer to cook turkey)
- [Java Resource Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735025/java-resource-pool) (Thanksgiving Turkey)

Your title:

> JS and JQuery syntax: understanding a real example

What it should probably be:

> what does the catcomplete function do in JQuery's autocomplete plugin?

**The problem statement**:  You start out with a very meta problem statement:

> I've tried to analyze this piece of JQuery code but for me was pretty hard to understand what is it doing. I've googled for "JQuery catcomplete" but it's not a part of the framework.
>
> Also the advanced JS syntax is not completely clear to me. Of course I've tried to google for JS ({}) without success.
>
> Yes, I could read the JS manual and then the JQuery one, but I think this question can be useful also for whoever is starting with JS and JQuery if put in a nice didactic way.

All of that can be axed and we would not lose any essential information from your question.

You could switch that with the following problem statement, which is essentially a longer form question from your title, or alternatively you can use it to describe the problem and your constraints:

> I don't know what autocomplete does in Jquery or how it works.  I see a `catcomplete` function, but I don't understand its purpose.  Here is the code I have a problem with.

(Or in Thanksgiving-ese):

> I need to be able to cook a turkey using a deep fryer.  The problem is, I don't know how to use a deep fryer to cook a turkey, and I don't even know what supplies I need to cook said turkey.

**Framing the problem**:  Your actual problem should be one thing.  If you find yourself putting in multiple question marks, that's the red flag that you're asking too much in one question.

Great interviewers often will ask a very simple question and let the interviewee talk.  For instance, asking "What was it like growing up?" to an NFL star is better than, "You've said your mom was your inspiration; how was it that she was your inspiration? Was it in helping you every day? Or that she took care of you and your siblings by herself? Or was it that she never gave up?"

Great questions do the same thing.

Instead of blocking answerers into a particular path, great questions ask what needs to be asked and get out of the way; they don't assume that they need to frame the question in a particular way for a particular set of constructs (unless it's truly necessary).

For instance, this is a very simple question, yet it has a very detailed answer:

> [Why do we use arrays instead of other data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392397/why-do-we-use-arrays-instead-of-other-data-structures/392426?s=14%7C0.0000#392426)

Overall, your question was downvoted because it didn't follow these three principles.  There may be other things to do to make your question well received, but without these three sections, there's no hope of having a great question.

Comment: It's Thanksgiving? Judging by previous interactions with the OP they're from Southern Europe so the analogy may not strike the note you're looking for...

Comment: @Ben I write what I know. It's approaching Thanksgiving in the US.

Comment: Oh, lord, +100 for the cooking translations, `Using Hammer to cook turkey` is a perl!

Comment: My real compliment a really really good answer. ps: I'm looking for a book which teaches me to frame more and avoid verbosity, if you have any advice I would really love.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Wondering why you re-opened the question... isn't it encouraging users to post *"I've tried to improve my downvoted question/answer, can you check it?"* questions here, kind of *featuring* posts without a bounty..? Or is this *the canonical* example for why one shouldn't do so..? :P

Comment: @T J: the question was improved and reopened. In the process, we've improved communication and reached a wider audience. I don't see any downside here.