# Would cap downvoting have a positive or negative fallback?

Tags: discussion

The voting system on Stack Exchange community is a very great tool, many users complain about downvotes seeing them as personal and punitive. This is completely false and even if people can perceive many downvotes as harsh and the whole mechanism imperfect, it's not that big deal.

The objective behind the voting system is

- discouraging poor quality questions
- having an objective validation of the quality of a question

The question is: **does avoiding a cap of downvotes fulfil this objectives?**

The only way to have a trustworthy answer is to make an A/B test organized with very strict parameters. Refer to [Evidence Based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence-based_practice) for getting a better knowledge.

Without a specific experiment we can just base our opinions on previous social experiments. The one which I'm citing were done by two famous social psychologists: [Robert Cialdini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cialdini) and [Elliot Aronson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliot_Aronson).

**Pros of having more than 2 or 3 downvotes in a question**

- teaching people that they must put an effort to write a good question (my opinion)
- avoiding the website to become like Yahoo Answer (my opinion)
- It's not so terrible to get a downvote (my opinion)

**Cons of having more than 2 or 3 downvotes in a question**

- it's scientifically proved that *people tend to replicate the behavior of the majority* (see [social proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_proof)) . This effect is so strong that can work also during homicide (see "[Genovese Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Kitty_Genovese#Psychological_research))" → many downvotes or many upvotes are not trustworthy unless they are invisible to the other voters.
- People tend to be strongly emotional and pseudo rational thought follow (→ see [rationalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology))). A strongly downvoted question shows mostly that it hurted someone emotions (i.e. this refers to the interpretations of the post)
- All human beings tend to take thing personally. It's related to a feature called [cognitive fusion](https://www.mindfulnessmuse.com/acceptance-and-commitment-therapy/fusion-vs-defusion), personality defence mechanism and self serving bias → Many downvotes may hurt people's ego. The number of polemics on downvotes excess may provide a strong evidence of this hypothesis. So it seems to be  pretty common to *perceive* too many downvotes as a punishment.
- There is a strong difference between saying "the voting system works" and "it works better if not capped". The inability to perceive any difference between the two statement is bound to an istinct called [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). People tend to defend their opinions.
- People are often unable to recognize their irrational behavior and their error in reasoning → see [cognitive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias) and [distortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion). Both are in all human beings, no one excluded.
- Most of people, included moderators and people who got strongly downvoted, tend to defend in a very irrational and strong way their ideas once they have publicly expressed their position → See [Commitment and Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cialdini#Six_key_principles_of_influence)
- it's pretty easy to find posts were downvoters were completely wrong. We are humans we make mistakes.

**Question:**

Has there been any statistical investigation to check if capping downvotes would improve or degrade the objectivity of the voting system and the customer satisfaction?

Comment: Not a single one of your "cons" is actually relevant to the existence of a cap.  Even if your assertions were all correct (which I would dispute) they would all apply equally even if there was a cap in place.

Comment: @Servy: can you please explain better how? Having 200 downvotes and 2 downvotes would hurt the ego of persons in the same way? This is what you are stating? A mistake of -60 is hard to being correct as a mistake of 2?

Comment: @Servy: you see what I mean? This small logical mistakes in your reasoning are easily explained by the "confirmation bias". When we say "all", "none", "completely" we are already making mistakes. It's an example of black and white cognitive distortion. But, most important, everything has to be proven. We tend to confuse our opinions with the absolute Truth. Evidence Based is something near to the truth the rest is just ego..

Comment: A person with a post at -200 has posted content that is *much more problematic* than one that is at -2, so I would expect someone to *justifiably* be more concerned, because they've done something much more wrong.  It's a *good* thing for someone to be much more concerned if they've posted a -200 post, and they're getting that *valuable feedback* that they've done something that's not just wrong, but *very* wrong.

Comment: @Servy: "A person with a post at -200 has posted content that is much more problematic than one that is at -2" - it's absolutely not sure, read about the "Genovese effect". As I stated it's your opinion against social psychology.

Comment: Stating that I've made a logical mistake doesn't really mean anything.  What did I say that was mistaken, and what's your reasoning for why it is mistaken?  Just asserting that I'm mistaken without any evidence or support for your position doesn't mean anything.

Comment: You're talking about capping downvoting as if not doing it would be illogical. Also, you're not taking the voters feeling in perspective. If a question had that 3 downvotes, and I would feel it was a really bad question, I would want to do something about this. Votes are a good way of signaling others that a question isn't properly asked. Limiting downvotes removes this power from the users.

Comment: Also: `It's pretty easy to find posts were downvoters were completely wrong`? I doubt that's true for more than 3 downvotes, and single downvotes can still be wrongfully placed.

Comment: So you're saying that you're completely confident, with absolute certainty, that all posts that have a negative score are equally problematic and have exactly the same problematic value?  You've just done the exact thing that you're claiming shouldn't be done.  Sure, votes aren't a perfect metric of quality, they're an approximation, but they've been shown to be a useful approximation nonetheless.  While it is certainly possible that, in certain exceptional situations, a given post's score won't accurately reflect its quality, it *is* a useful signal as it true often enough.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Examples exist, even with more than 3 votes, they're just *very* rare.  (Exceptions of course exist in the other direction, where completely invalid posts get quite a few upvotes.)  People are fallible.  The point is simply that the votes are accurate *enough* to be useful to readers, even though readers should always take a post score with some degree of salt.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: "you're not taking the voters feeling in perspective." - I'm just saying that the topic should be analyzed more carefully. Social psychology can answer also questions about the voting system and its efficacy (especially in the schools).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: "It's pretty easy to find posts were downvoters were completely wrong? I doubt that's true for more than 3 downvotes, and single downvotes can still be wrongfully placed." I can provide you a very hard to argument against example. The question was opened by a user with a HUGE reputation.

Comment: @Servy: no, I'm just saying that we should think of this problem without being sure to already have the truth in our hand.. let's REALLY discuss the question. Not with me only but between you also or asking on cogsci.stackexchange

Comment: @Revious yes, please do. Examples help questions, but as you probably know when referencing statistics and social science, n=1 doesn't say a lot. If you can provide us with multiple recent questions that suffered from excessive (>3) incorrect downvotes, that would certainly increase the validity of your point.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: ok, but please don't fall into rethoric. I cannot spend hours in searching recent questions which have been excessively downvoted. I've spoken of confirmation bias, commitment and consistency. The part here should not make my search harder but sincerely wonder if I could be right or not. Schopenhauer said something interesting on that. Dialectic could be used to find the truth or... to serve our ego. Please don't make an ego war. I will look for some examples.

Comment: @Revious So you're saying that because you can't be bothered to provide evidence to support your extreme accusation, that flies in the face of considerable evidence and established facts, we should just accept your extremely bold claims without evidence and make radical changes to the system?  That's...not how things work.  If you expect people to be convinced that your position has merit, you're going to need to provide evidence to support it, rather than just telling people that you're right and that we should believe your rhetoric alone.

Comment: @Revious I'm not bothering you with homework just to annoy you, I just sincerely doubt if there are actual good questions that get incorrectly downvoted more than 3 times shortly after being asked (they still can get incorrectly downvoted up to 3 times if we cap it). For longer existing questions, certainly, misplaced downvotes can accumulate, just as misplaced upvotes can, but their relevance is limited (since questions tend to get answered within the first few days) (and of course, meta doesn't count, since downvotes here express disagreement and don't reflect on the quality of the question)

Comment: We are more than willing to look into the problem. Provided there IS a problem. So yes the onus is on you to prove the point you are trying to make. It's not homework, it's just proving your theory. You advanced a lot of claims using social science. None of these points are relevant if we can't see an example of these behaviors in place. So unless you can provide a couple of valid examples, this will likely not go anywhere. And I love how you think that a user with high rep = automatic good questions... isn't this an "argument from authority" fallacy?

Comment: "it's pretty easy to find posts were downvoters were completely wrong." But not a single example given...

Comment: You did seem to provide an example [at Data Science Meta](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/reasons-for-constant-downvoting-in-deep-learning-questions/2321#comment1343_2321), but I disagree that it represents a case of inappropriate downvoting. Questions are expected to show more effort than "what does X do?".

Comment: capping at 3 seems absurd to me. That would mean we are to trust 3-6 (because we'd have to cap upvotes too) users and ignore the opinions of the rest of the community that happens upon that post. It would disallow the possibility of something having, say, 10 upvotes and 5 downvotes, because you'd cap at 3/3 before getting there. we'd lose valuable information.

Comment: My highest scoring answer would have a score of 0 rather than 157. How is that useful?

Comment: I did warn you to properly research before posting. Looks like you didn't take my advice. I fully disagree with this suggestion.

Comment: I can't recall seeing a pile-on that wasn't the result of one of the following: wildly off topic question, homework dump, extremely common duplicate, OP actively refusing to provide clarification in comments, OP being rude in comments (or post or on meta), edit wildly changing a question after being answered, answer being flat out wrong, answer is not actually an answer. There are posts that eventually get a lot of down votes over time but getting slammed with a lot of down votes at once usually requires more than just "already down voted once".

Comment: "Has there been any statistical investigation to check..." - if there has been, I am not aware of it. Please look at [SO Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), you may be able to devise some useful queries that may contribute to the investigation.

Comment: If we could not pile on 3+ downvotes quickly, we could not then pile on the three delete votes required to get rid of the rubbish.

Comment: ..and it's the usual 'we al know it happens, I am just not able to provide any evidence ATM because of xxxxxx', (AKA, there isn't any).

Comment: The compiler, linkers and other software tools that we use don't give a PHP about social issues and the inabilty of posters to deal with their own social inadequacies.  The tools issue three pages of error-messages to all, irrespective of their social standing or issues, so I don't see why we should pander excessively to those who insist on blaming everyone else for downvotes and inventing malice where none exists.  If they cannot cope with failure, they should find another profession/hobby because software development is certainly not for them.

Comment: If OP's cannot cope with downvotes, I wonder how they would respond to a death threat - something that was directed today at SO users who committed the heinous crime of umm.. downvoting some bad questions.

Comment: 'it's pretty easy to find posts were downvoters were completely wrong.  We are humans we make mistakes' sure.  When you post your list of links to Q&A that were wrongly downvoted, please exclude those that were corrected by upvotes and.or reopen votes.  Just the wrongly-downvoted that stuck, please. To be statistically significant agains the thousands of examples of utter crap that were justifiably and correctly downvoted, please list just the first 10.

Comment: I've read all the comments. I'd like to ask in which way may I reply to dozen of statements and which objective criterium would you suggest to adopt for avoiding rhetoric. What about moving to cogsci.stackexchange and asking some psychologist to moderate the conversation?

Comment: And also comments are not fitting this kind of discussion and it looks like people here don't have a scientific knowledge of the domain of the problem. How can we speak opionable against scientific evidences? What your suggestion?

Comment: Discarding people's opinions because, "They don't understand the topic" isn't going to fly here. Are you a programmer? Are we? Yes? Then we're just as qualified as you. Your reception is going to be *extremely* chilly if you try to pull the, "You don't know what you're talking about" card. Either argue on the merits of the discussion, or don't, but telling us you know better won't do anything but make people ignore you.

Comment: @fbueckert: it's not what I said. I said that SO tries to base not to highly opinionability and research for a scientific validation when it's available. As an old member you know it.

Comment: Yes, we do. And you'll notice that *you haven't provided any*. All you've done is presented a highly skewed, opinionated argument as to why to cap downvotes. Which, the community very much disagrees with. As I said before: learn what their purpose is. Do your research. There are *extremely* good reasons why the system works the way it does.

Comment: @fbueckert: I will put in evidence where you exchange your opinions for facts so you can stop saying things which are untruth and mind more attention the next time. I will also put in evidence where you behave as arrogant pretending to know, to judge others, and to be right. https://i.imgur.com/eVtGJxE.png
- If you have any topic showing A/B scientific experiments about capping downvotes I will appreciate if you share them. Thanks.

Comment: In a less abstract way, you are still saying that I don't understand how votes works but it's extremely clear to me.. it's so obvious that even a child can get it. I just miss why you have this idea.. I'm trying to say in a polite way, I hope you don't get offended.

Comment: If you understood it, you wouldn't have posted this. But, again, you haven't done your research; nowhere do I see evidence of your understanding the purpose of down votes; just an argument based on a false premise, and that capping down votes would be helpful. **Down votes are not punitive**. Understand it. They are an essential quality mechanism that is required to allow the system to work. We can discuss once you understand that.

Comment: @fbueckert: "Down votes are not punitive". I know it PERFECTLY. Its a bit weird that you still can't get this point. I wrote it many many times already, I suspect you DON'T read my comments... (sorry for caps lock but it's a very easy concept which I understand already some years ago, if you like I can explain you about human beings works on that topic.. it's not arrogance.. it's just that I studied that topic.)

Comment: Its really hard for me to believe that; the entire premise of this suggestion is to limit the perceived harm of down votes. If they're not harmful, what good is this suggestion? It has no basis at all. Despite you saying you understand that, I don't think you do.

Comment: @fbueckert: it doesn't matter if the intention is not to hurt people feeling, you have to check if they are usually hurted or not. You can better understand this when you study the origin of crimes.. criminals usually don't feel being "bad people". To be empathetic you should not look as YOU see downvotes but as they are PERCEIVED.

Comment: Have a short look to this article.. no one feels "bad" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techniques_of_neutralization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't agree with your proposed solution of limiting down-votes. Brad already addressed that in his answer and I don't have much to add to that.

I do agree with some of your observations, so let me expand on that a bit.

"You deserve all the down-votes you get if you provide crap content" is more or less the current meta zeitgeist, but that strikes me as ... cold, and lacking in kindness; and more importantly, it's not necessarily the most effective way of doing things. Most people respond better to criticism if it's stated in a kind and friendly (rather than harsh) way.

And make no mistake, receiving loads of down-votes is harsh. People on meta say that "down-votes shouldn't be taken personally", but as you already said they **do** get taken personally, and not a whole lot we say on meta is going to change that.

The question here is if can we do something about it, or is the current system simply "the worst system, except for all the other ones that have been tried"?

I'm not sure what the answer to that is, but I strongly suspect that we *can* do better.

For example, there is no reason we *need* to use the same indicator for both the author and the rest of the community. For example we could display the score to everyone except the author, who will see a textual description such as "excellent", "good", "neutral", or "poorly received". I suspect that such text labels would result in fewer hurt feelings and be more effective in prompting people to fix their question/answer.

In other words, the current system is fine, as such, it's just the communication that's not always ideal. It's the difference between telling someone that their question is stupid and lazy vs. telling them that they should consider buying a Python programming book to pick up the basics followed by some encouragement by telling them that learning to program was hard for all of us. Unfortunately, down-votes are closer to the first example than the second.

Comment: The main issue I have with that (and I usually am on for a kinder experience for everyone) is that going in nicely results in US getting abused. I got tired of being told to shut up and just answer questions. Granted, some OPs aren't rude and don't push back quite as hard... but  I agree we can still provide a slightly nicer feedback to the OPs. The one thing about your scale though is that it's skewed positively. If we have both "good" and "excellent" on the + scale, I'd believe we need to differenciate between "poorly received, try to edit it" and "poorly received, please nuke it from space"

Comment: Note that I'm not proposing to change the voting system itself @Patrice; that can stay as-is. Just the way those votes are displayed to the question author (and *only* the question author). It would be displayed the same for everyone else.

Comment: So your solution to "people get upset and take things personally when they're politely told that their post has problems" is "don't tell people when their post has problems, so they don't get upset".  That...just doesn't work.  If people aren't told that they're doing something wrong, they're going to keep doing what they're doing, and have no reason to change their behavior, and for the types of people that complain about downvotes, the problem is the mere act of being told that you're wrong, not that it's being done inappropriately.

Comment: I'm not proposing "don't tell people when their post has problems" at all @Servy. Just telling them that in a different way. I *suspect* that this way will be more effective in getting people to fix their crap (testing will have to prove that), which is what we want.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker And what different way are you proposing?  For most people the problem is the mere act of being informed that they're wrong that is problematic, regardless of the manner.

Comment: @Servy Well, I proposed using text labels instead of vote counts in my answer, which is a reasonably simple change. Or perhaps there is another better way I haven't thought of. Either way, I suspect we can do better than just "score: -6". I also don't agree that "For most people the problem is the mere act ...". It is for *some*, certainly, but not "most".

Comment: wouldn't it be more clear to use the label "Not useful/Poorly Researched/Unclear"? What does poorly received even mean to the OP? Poorly Received doesn't necessarily indicate a problem with the post itself.

Comment: I would very much disagree with that. People are already defensive when they receive negative feedback, and attaching labels to it doesn't change that. I've lost count of the number of times new users respond to critique with, "if you don't know, then shut up and let someone else answer". They don't want opposition; they want an answer, and don't care about quality standards.

Comment: I'm a nice guy and great mentor, but the last thing I want to do is to have to fish a question out of someone asking me for help.  If you don't fully understand what you're asking about or you don't provide a good, clear thing that you're asking about, I see nothing cruel about downvoting your post.  On the contrary, I find it cruel for one to assume that I'm being cold on purpose, or that I do this out of some vindictive nature.  I don't care what you're asking.  If it isn't well-formed, you're getting downvotes.  You may not like that, but I value my time *slightly* more than your feelings.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't say it **is** "cruel" (not the word I used, but okay), but it is how it's **perceived**, that's not quite the same. I also never said people shouldn't down-vote – quite the opposite – just that perhaps it might be more effective to present it to authors in a different way. If anything, this might encourage *more* down-voting.

Comment: It seems to be already having that effect

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I would estimate anywhere from 95-99% of responses are negative; even on Arqade, where I'm most active, the same attitude persists; shut up and help, screw quality. And as I'm a very prolific commentor, I get more than my fair share of hate. Not always from new users, either. The point is that users have to adapt to the community, and most don't care to even try.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that the negative emotions expand to fill the allowed space, as seen in grade inflation phenomenon. People who now feel bad for receiving > 3 downvotes will feel just as bad about being "poorly received" after a while. Eventually anything that's not "excellent" will be considered abuse.

Comment: Cold, and lacking in kindness.. you mean, like, say, a compiler?

Comment: _"the current meta zeitgeist"_ Possible duplicate of [the recency illusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/9953/1).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker and where in my comment do you feel I didn't realize that? I never mentioned voting once, only said that your scale should go 2 in the positive and 2 in the negative as well.... I'm not sure how your answer relates to my comment, to be fair

Comment: @Patrice Your comment `we need to differenciate between "poorly received, try to edit it" and "poorly received, please nuke it from space"` seems to imply that something needs to change in the way you vote, otherwise there's no way to differentiate between the two "poorly received"s; at least, that's how I interpreted that...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker oh. Yeah no that was definitely a misunderstanding. I meant if we differenciate +5 questions (good) and +10 questions (excellent), we should also differentiate bad (-5) and terrible (-10). The wording of my labels was definitely not along those lines. Mea culpa for the confusion

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't get it. There is nothing "harsh" about a downvote. It's *way* nicer than some snarky comments, so I am all for driving people towards the downvote button instead of the "add comment" link. The chances that someone who would otherwise downvote would leave a snarky comment are just too high. It's also *way* too much effort---the amount of effort users spend interacting with a low-quality post should be commensurate with the amount of effort that the poster put into it. It's nice to think that everything should be kitties and flowers, but reality says different.

Comment: I see this argument presented a lot, so I want to think that it might have some merit, but I just cannot see it, no matter how many times I evaluate it. (Similar to certain other arguments currently circulating in popular political discourse.) I just don't follow the assumption that a downvote is "harsh", or that it says a person is "stupid and lazy". It doesn't do any of those things. It serves as an indicator that a post is unclear or not interesting to your peers (i.e., other software developers). It's no different than your "excellent", "good", etc. scale, except it's quantitative.

Comment: I would maybe have some sympathy with the OP's position if compilers and linkers were restricted to only three error-messages and, after dealing with only those three errors, code is guaranteed to build cleanly.  There - issue solved, just a socially-aware toolchain needed!

Comment: @Servy "So your solution to "people get upset and take things personally when they're politely told that their post has problems" is "don't tell people when their post has problems, so they don't get upset". That...just doesn't work. If people aren't told that they're doing something wrong" - there are several cognitive distortion in what you wrote.. first you assume that who downvotes is right and the other deserved that, but this is just an opinion which you have absolutized. Now by telling it kindly to you you will stop making this mistake? Are you taking it personally?

Comment: One possible solution is to take 2 votes away from the reputation of downvoters when a "jury" estabilishes thatt the downvoting for the specific question were wrong or excessive. According to @Servy POV this could help to avoid the repeating error.

Comment: @CodyGray: " 
I'm sorry, but I just don't get it. There is nothing "harsh" about a downvote." - psychology explains that this are just opinions / convinctions. Please refer to cognitive psychology for a scientific view. Nothing in the world *is* but many things *are perceived* as..

Comment: @Revious That's another one of those oft-suggested, never will be implemented ideas. Its about as common as requiring down voters to comment why they're doing so. Flip it around, man; apply those same requirements to upvotes; do they make sense? Almost certainly not. Therefore, they also don't belong on downvotes.

Comment: "Cognitive psychology"..."scientific" <-- tee hee

Comment: @CodyGray: tee hee = laughing of me? My answer: I see you are not used to get informed before speaking.. look for evidence based on wikipedia or ask cogsci.stackexchange.

Comment: Can we stop bickering and speak in a mature way if someone is still interested?

Comment: @Revious So you just *assume* that everyone who ever tells anyone that they think there is a problem with one of their contributions *must* be wrong, so you feel it's essential that we prohibit *anyone* from providing feedback instead.  That just doesn't work.  Sure, some people will incorrectly evaluate the quality of a post, it happens, I never said otherwise, but the feedback is useful nonetheless, and there are many tools in place to mitigate and deal with individuals that are not providing accurate feedback on the quality of posts, making the feedback mechanism as a whole very useful.

Comment: You have absolutized the opinion that all downvoters are always wrong, entirely incorrectly, and you've absolutized the opinion that I feel votes are infallible, despite the fact that I've indicated the opposite *many* times.  Rather than providing anything to support your position, all you're doing is accusing people of saying things when *they have specifically said the opposite of those things*.  Now will you kindly stop making this mistake?  Are you taking it personally?

Comment: @Servy: "So you just assume that everyone who ever tells anyone that they think there is a problem with one of their contributions must be wrong". No. But I think it's so obvious that just someone very very ignorant could take a similar supposition that I wonder why you are making it. It looks like a "straw man" argument.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man - what I'm saying that there is a difference between evaluating the quality of a question and obviously emotional downvoting and if we want to discourage non-constructive behaviour we could start from the second..

Comment: Let me show you an example and please just accept that people who downvoted are non constructive and express a proposal on how to fight this issue. What I mean is: stop speaking of "How many angels can dance on the head of a pin?", let's admit there is a problem and see how we can deal with it.

Comment: @Revious *You* are the one saying that we should prohibit people from providing feedback because you're afraid that they *might* not *always* reflect *your* opinion of the quality of the post.  That's, frankly, absurd, and also a wild and extreme position that you've put forth and provided *no* evidence whatsoever that it's merited, or would be helpful to the site.   You have not demonstrated that the behavior you claim to happen is happening, you haven't demonstrated that it's a significant problem, and you've failed to address that your "cure" would cause *significant* damage to the site.

Comment: @Servy: no, I'm NOT saying that we should prohibit people from providing feedback, this is already a misunderstanding of my words. You are not taking into account the concept of measure. This mistake is called all or nothing thinking or false dichotomy. Now can we assume you got me on this point?

Comment: @Revious You can't just say,"There exists an example that I won't show you, so you should just blindly accept, without any evidence whatsoever, that I'm right and that this problem exists, and so we should do enormous amounts of damage to essential features of the site purely on my word that it's a good idea."  Things don't work like that.  If you want people to know it's a problem, *demonstrate* that it's a problem, don't just ask them to accept it on faith.

Comment: @Servy: wait a second.. you jump easily to wrong conclusions and tend to interpret my words in an extreme way. But it's just your interpretation... can you ask in this way: "are yo stating this?"

Comment: @Revious Oh, so you're *not* planning to introduce a feature that would prevent people from being able to vote on whether or not they feel a post is a good post, so when you said in the question that we should prevent certain people from being able to downvote post you weren't actually suggesting that we prevent them from giving feedback you were just...what?  What are you proposing if you're not proposing prevent those people from giving feedback on the quality of the post?

Comment: @Revious If you feel my conclusions are wrong, then explain how they're wrong.  *Stating* that I'm wrong with no explanation for how I am wrong is meaningless.

Comment: @Servy: I'm proposing to take a serious and constructive discussion on how to deal with EXCESSIVE, EMOTIONAL, UNCONSTRUCTIVE downvoting. Now can I show you an example of this? Without you proposing "arbitrary interpretation of what I'm saying?

Comment: Ok, have a look to this example

Comment: This question got strongly downvoted, maybe it wasn't perfect so I opened a question on how to improve it on meta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655534/what-is-catcomplete-in-jquerys-autocomplete-plugin

Comment: @Revious I'm not stopping you from providing an example to support your position.  In fact, I've told you *many* times how it's problematic for you to make the claims that you're making without supporting your position.  I've been *asking* you to support your position, not preventing you from doing so.

Comment: @Revious So you're example of "emotional and unconstructive" downvoting is people downvoting a question that you personally agree is not a good question and that needs improving, and is therefore a question that merits being downvoted.  That's...not supporting your position.  You've just demonstrated a case of people *accurately* providing feedback that a question that *you agree is bad* is in fact bad, and the result of that is that you've been incentivised to try to figure out how to improve it.  Huzzah!  The system works.

Comment: @Servy: ok, let's say the first version was not ok. So I asked how to improve it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276011/ive-tried-to-improve-a-question-can-you-check-it/276025#276025 and I got it revised and approved by a member with 42.7k reputation

Comment: What do you expect to have happened to the question after a revision of an expert in good questions and answers? Do you think social psychology has predicted the behavior or people have started to behave rationally?

Comment: Now, please fight against your confirmation bias and your Commitment and Consistency bias and try to be intellectually honest.

Comment: The topic which this community loves so much "doesn't show effort" is just an easy universal topic, but if you look and put effort you can easily confirm that this is not the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558754/define-what-is-a-hashset

Comment: Another example of absolutely no-effort-made and upvoting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582694/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-aria-describedby-property

Comment: So please.. don't fall into rethoric and just bring on a mature conversation. The voting system is not perfect and it's possible to correct without extreme measures.

Comment: @Revious  You asked how to improve it, and it became better than it was, but it's still not a good question even after all of the edits, it's just less bad.  The fact that a user with a lot of reputation edited your question doesn't magically mean it's now a great question.  It's better than it was, but still not good.  The fact that you've continued to edit your question afterwards, making it worse every time, also doesn't help.

Comment: @Servy: not great != -60 negtive feedback. Why continue editing a question should not help? Are you stating that that score is near to be objective?

Comment: @Revious So you're going around claiming that your question is getting downvotes because of biases in the voters, despite *acknowledging that the question is bad and merits downvotes*.  You are completely disproving all of your own points with your example.  You're showing that *you* are the one who's biased here, and that you're just upset that your post is being *justifiably* downvoted, and *maliciously* and *erroneously* claiming a bias in others to attempt to absolve yourself of your own responsibility to ask a good question.

Comment: @Servy: try to get one point. When you speak of your opinion you use words as "acknoledging", when you speak of other opinions you use more opinionable adjective. Can you correct this extreme bias from you?

Comment: @Revious Continuing to edit a question *when your edits are still resulting in the question as a bad question* is indeed not super productive.  Making a question less bad isn't harmful, but it's not going to stop you from getting downvotes.  You need to actually edit your question into one that's actually a *good* question that merits upvotes if you want to actually turn the tide and make those edits productive.

Comment: @Servy: you are showing to be completely unable to distinguish facts from opinions. May you try at least?

Comment: If you want I can evidence how much subjectivity you put in every sentence that you take as certain..

Comment: @Revious I used "acknowledging" to refer to *your* opinions, not mine.  "acknowledging" is not an "opinionable adjective"; it's a statement of fact that you acknowledged what I said you acknowledged.  Your assertions make no sense at all, and are not a demonstration of any type of bias at all (or of anything for that matter).

Comment: @Revious You are demonstrating a complete inability to distinguish facts from opinions.  Would you try at least?

Comment: This part are completely subjective... https://i.imgur.com/faos7xS.png

Comment: @Revious Rather than telling me that you could explain how I'm wrong, you should *actually* explain how I'm wrong.  Stating that I'm wrong without actually providing anything to back that up is meaningless.  If you can provide evidence that I'm claiming something as certain that isn't certain, then by all means, provide that evidence, don't just say that you can.

Comment: @Servy: you are assuming that I'm upset and I'm not. You are assuming that I'm not objective since I took as an example also an old question of mine. These are strong bias.. you have to prove this convinction from you

Comment: I just wrote...

Comment: Try to read what you wrote and wonder yourself: "can I prove this? with which evidence?". The cognitive distortion you are using is called "mind reading".

Comment: @Revious Many of those points are subjective, yes.  I never said otherwise.  I *did* however back up those points with evidence (something you appear to be largely unfamiliar with doing).  Rather than just stating that you're disproving your own position, I *explained* how  you're doing so (that you've provided an example of a question *you think is bad* and providing it as evidence that people downvote good questions).

Comment: I showed you many examples not just one of mistakes in evaluation and also the one that you blame is not qualitatively bad compared to others (after revision by an experienced user). You proved to have a strong confirmation bias by the other judgements you expressed on me, and tend to jump to conclusions. It's normal.. it's very common, but you interpret a lot and express always as you were sure. And you are still doing that also in the last comment... if you like we can go on speaking but without a cognitive pattern it's very hard to get aware of our way of being..

Comment: ps: +1 vote for being aware of your subjectivity

Comment: BTW another duplicate of my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830594/partitioning-a-graph-into-connected-subgraphs-with-sets-of-vertices-that-must-be has been positively accepted. It's very funny.. the same question doesn't show effort but here it got upvoted.

Comment: Ah, also the PERFECT duplicate of my question in differend meta got different vote. Very strange if the voting system works so well.

Comment: I'm going to make a few final comments here, because I'm starting to think we're feeding a troll. Your first example, as already explained, shows poor quality, and so was downvoted. The other three examples of "questions that don't show effort yet were upvoted" are from 2010 and 2011, back when the standards of quality were much more relaxed. Using these as any sort of evidence pertaining to what is happening in present time is inappropriate.

Answer (score 38):

Pile-ons for voting can happen in both directions. To make this truly "objective", you'd need to cap voting in the positive direction, too. That's clearly not going to happen, so any cap on downvotes allowed would skew voting in the positive direction.

If you allow unlimited upvotes and limit downvotes, you get the biased voting we currently see in comments. 100 people might think something is wrong, but five people think it's right, so a comment shows as a score of 5 even if it's wildly wrong or harmful. This has bothered me for a while, and I think SE should revisit allowing downvotes on comments for just this reason. People should be able to express that something is incorrect as freely as they do that something is correct.

Since we're talking about the psychological influence of seeing a vote score as someone is voting on a post, maybe you meant that downvotes should be hidden to the viewer below a certain threshold. Cap the displayed sum of votes at -4 or something, so that people can still cast more downvotes but the lowest score ever shown for a post it -4.

First, the pile-on effect for voting starts the instant something flips into positive or negative territory, so I don't know that any cap other than 0 would make a significant impact on this.

Once again, you'd have to provide an argument why the opposite shouldn't also be true and a cap placed on displayed positive score. If you limit displayed negative scores but not positive scores, wouldn't that skew overall voting to the positive and make things less objective? I'm not as certain about this as I am about limiting the votes themselves, but I bet that'd be the case.

To be completely objective when it comes to voting, you'd have to hide the score until the point someone votes. That negates the core value of the SE system, so that's not going to happen.

Comment: +1. Yes, you are right.. if the objective of voting would be reaching the mosto objective score for the question, according to social psychology, we can suppose that the previous voter's score should be hidden. (see the point on social proof). Anyway first of all a serious objective speaking about the voting system should start on what are the objectives?

Comment: One of course is involvement of users, especially the kind of users which answer a lot. Rewarding them, making them feel part of a community is one of the primary objectives.

Comment: Another important objective is to easily find the more fitting answer.

Comment: Another is discouraging unconstructive behaviours.

Comment: (sorry if I write in many comments.. it's a bit problematic since I don't have formatting here)

Comment: Now, as you can easily check, downvoting is not discouraging non constructive behaviors but simply favors pre-built standard answers which often do not fit at all the specific question. Have a look to this question. It was perfectly ok, as I will prove in a few seconds, but not fitting on SO.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356250/which-stack-exchange-site-would-this-question-fit-on
- The comments are completely misleading, the community did a poor job.

Comment: The same question was well received on other two section where it fits better: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2837/50702, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/can-this-question-fit-here - the only suggestion I got is: "why did you asked in the meta instead of on the main site?"

Comment: We both know that SE have to deal with many different people from 15 to 60 years old and that managing communities require an autoritative approach, but the system is perfectible and if someone really wants to get deeper I'm open to speak of it. If not, no problem

Comment: _"One of course is involvement of users, especially the kind of users which answer a lot."_ Although there is indeed a need for people to answer questions, that is only secondary to the main goal of [creating a repository of programming knowledge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292176/1233251).

Comment: _"Now, as you can easily check, downvoting is not discouraging non constructive behaviors but simply favors pre-built standard answers which often do not fit at all the specific question."_ Not at all, it actually prevents people from wasting their time with poor quality questions. Your examples are from Meta sites, which obviously do not function the same way. If the communities around them agree that such a question could be on-topic, then they won't be displaying the same form of disagreement as shown here.