# A way to stop "pile on" downvoting

Tags: discussion, downvotes

It is clear that there are egregiously bad questions that deserve more than one downvote ... to get the message through to the person who posted the Question.

But it is also clearly a bad experience for someone who has made an innocent mistake.  Under most circumstances one downvote is enough to let the user know that they have made a mistake.

So how do we stop people just piling on the downvotes?

Here's a suggestion.  Make downvotes on Questions have a variable cost on reputation.

- If the Question currently has a net vote score >= zero, the reputation cost is zero.
- If the Question currently has a net voting score of -1, the reputation cost is -2.
- If the Question currently has a net voting score of -N, the reputation cost is -2<sup>N</sup>.

This would discourage most people from dumping yet another downvote.

Now I can see that there would be difficulties in implementing this.  For a start, it would be necessary to record you much each down-vote cost the down-voter in case they decided to reverse the vote.  (But the easy solution is to make the reputation non-refundable!)

What do people think?

---

**UPDATE** - Maybe the threshold of -1 is too high:

- What do people think of only penalizing "piling on" behavior if the threshold was beyond -3?  Or -5?
- What if there was a popup that said: *"Dear user: this downvote is going to cost you -100 reputation points, do you really want to do it?"*

Is anyone here arguing that "piling on" the negative votes is actually helpful / good for the StackOverflow community?   If so, why?  Put it in an Answer please, so that other people can express their opinions on your arguments by voting on your Answer ...

Comment: _Casts downvote before reading question, just in case it's bad, to not lose rep_

Comment: That'd loose you nearly all your rep if you were the 20th downvoter on a question, Stephen.

Comment: What proportion of really bad questions are due to 'innocent mistakes', and how many are,due to selfish deadbeats trying to con other users into doing research, homework, paid work and/or 'Computers 101'unpaid private tuition?

Comment: Why does the fact that an "innocent mistake" has been made affect the quality of the question itself? Downvotes are content rating mechanisms, serving the exact opposite purpose of upvotes. They're not "punishment"; they cannot be "piled on". One person; one vote.

Comment: I think the idea is right, you are judt trying to fix it on the wrong side. On the curators end, downvoting is an important measure of quality. But for the OP, it does not matter wether the question was downvoted once, twice or ten times.

Comment: @JonasWilms when my first question got downvoted, my defense mechanism kicked in and I assumed “ok one person didn’t get how great this question actually is”, only after fifth downvote did I consider to follow the how to ask link in the comment. Different people will react differently to amount of critique.

Comment: @ead yes, I try to be that kind of person too ... but honestly sometimes I do take downvotes personal. And there's another thing: Downvotes are proportional to attention. Just link a closeworthy question here on Meta and you'll get from -2 to -20 ...

Comment: I like that approach, give more power to the reputation "rich" people and try to discourage people with lower reputation to cast their votes.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is a specific plan separate to the duplicate target.

Comment: *"That'd loose you nearly all your rep if you were the 20th downvoter on a question, Stephen."* - Would that be a bad thing?   Seriously, is there ever any good reason to downvote a StackOverflow question that is on a net -20 score?

Comment: @Tom - well sure.  But from the community perspective, we don't want / need *anyone* to be punishing people by downvoting questions into oblivion.  (And I would hope that the high reputation ("rich") users already know that.  But, hey, if they want to burn their reputation, that's their business.)

Comment: Better to show the score logarithmically. Even better to have people vote for a point on a logarithmic score & show the distribution.

Comment: That "punishment" argument again ... you know very well that votes are not against the user, thus can't be punishment. I wonder why you argue for that approach instead of capping the downvotes at a certain level. Also rich users have far less issues with their reputation when downvoting a -2 question to -3 (which would cost 4 points) than low-rep users. So you're punishing (I use that word since you seem to like that analogy) low-rep people for expressing their opinion using a system that is designed to exactly that.

Comment: @Tom - I am talking about people who participate in a down-vote fests.  Not people who ask poor questions.  And yes, I do think "pile on" needs to be stopped.  STOPPED.  And if it takes punishment to change people's behavior, then lets punish people.  People don't need to express their opinions by heaping downvotes on someone's question.  It is anti-social. If they really, really, really want to do it, let them pay.

Comment: @Tom - you appear to be one of the people the last paragraph of my Q is astion is addressed to.  I challenge you to write an answer that expresses why you think it is a good thing to dump masses of downvotes on certain questions, and why you think it is good for the community to do so.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, you're talking about voters punishing the OPs and I said that this can't (or shouldn't) be considered punishment against the OPs. Also what you want to achieve is clear, but it is unclear why you chose this way instead of capping the amount of downvotes possible on a post. Wouldn't that be much easier? Let's take your reputation count as an example, why should someone care if a downvote costs nothing or 8 or 20 or whatever? With 500k it doesn't matter and can hardly be called punishment. And I don't think people with low rep participate in downvoting that much.

Comment: @Tom - OK.  So lets make the punishment proportional to the downvoter's current reputation.  Or *super-proportional*.  I'm happy with that.

Comment: Besides, I think it is rather offensive to imply that it is the high reputation users who do the "pile on" downvoting.  They have a more constructive / effective way to deal with egregiously bad questions.  Start a closure vote. *"And I don't think people with low rep participate in downvoting that much."* - What is your evidence?

Comment: This proposal has similar problems to vote capping: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356258/1233251

Comment: I didn't said it is the high-rep users who do the pile on, I said (or at least meant) that downvotes are mainly from higher-rep users who participate in maintaining this site. Regarding evidence: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1135825/average-cast-downvotes-by-reputation#graph ... the downvotes rise with increased reputation, but not that strong as I first thought and it doesn't take account age into consideration, so I it isn't that strong as evidence :/ (I hope rene comes around to bring us a better query)

Comment: I don't like the proposed solution. I would much more prefer if we would stop displaying questions with a score of -5 or less until they are edited at least once.

Answer (score 35):

Yea, no.

The problem here is that downvotes are seen as "unwelcoming" and "not nice".
It's just a quality control mechanism.

Sure, a single downvote may not be the most happy experience, but when there's multiple, there's usually something very wrong with the question.

If a question is *that* bad that it ends up getting downvoted beyond, say, -3, it's often either spam, rude, or so extremely common that it has a bazillion of dupes already.

That's not a *"simple mistake"*. That's a lack of research / effort, or even ill intent.

What you're proposing is a change that would make the third downvote, the one that makes a question deletable, cost ***8*** rep, while removing any incentive *not* to downvote a freshly posted question, by making that downvote free of charge.

Comment: Not to mention this opens up a lot of opportunity for trickery, such as upvoting a very bad -1-scored question so someone else can downvote it, only to retract the upvote within the 5-minute window

Answer (score 20):

Downvotes used to cost reputation, [but that cost was removed because users were not using their votes often enough because of the reputation cost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not).

Despite downvotes on questions being "free", [these are still much less prevalent than upvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/607410/community-voting-statistics-of-stack-overflow#graph), although the amount of bad questions does not seem to have decreased lately:

> [image: votes over time graph]

*(Kudos to rene for the nice SEDE query)*

Adding back a cost for downvoting questions (even more so such a high cost, or even worse a non-refundable cost) would tilt the balance even more towards upvoting, making systems that depend on voting (like the question ban, home-page suppression, etc) much harder to work effectively.

Not to mention the detrimental effects on question curation in general, since bad questions would be **much** harder to delete.

Comment: I've also one that is [per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813466/up-accept-and-down-votes-over-time#graph)

Comment: I'd be terribly disappointed if you didn't. ;) But I think the yearly aggregation does a better job at showing the voting trends, without the noisy monthly swings.

Comment: Does this include votes on deleted content? If not, it could be skewed.

Answer (score 7):

Considering that downvotes are not "punishment" should tell you that your perspective is misaligned.  Misinterpretation is a common problem with many of the network's features, but the answer to that isn't to make it harder to show your judgment of a post.  It's to educate users about the actual purpose of those votes.

There are going to be cases where votes are "piled on"; that happens, and it's unfortunate.  The *vast* majority of those, however, are going to happen from questions that are brought to attention here on Meta, which is frequented by the most quality-minded users of Stack Overflow.  The corollary is also true: posts can equally be "piled on" with upvotes, and I don't see anyone complaining about that.  Perhaps they also need a cost to prevent being piled on?

At the end of the day, downvotes are *important*.  Arguably, voting (in both directions) is one of the most important things users can do to help ensure the signal to noise ratio is as high as possible.  Downvotes also feed the automatic rate-limiting systems, like the question ban.  The less time future readers have to spend finding good quality content, the better.  We're here for *them*, not at the service of the original asker.

A good way to know if a barrier to downvotes will be acceptable is to apply the same barrier to upvotes.  If it sounds unreasonable when upvoting, it's *definitely* unreasonable when downvoting.  They both serve the same purpose: to rank content on its utility.  Bad content is bad content.

Comment: And how do you educate them?

Comment: By making it clearer what the purpose of downvotes are.  This doesn't mean that people will accept them for that purpose, but it doesn't change the fact that they're not punishment.  Right now, we get users on an almost daily basis coming to MSO to rant about their downvotes, and we have to, yet again, explain that they're not personal, they continue to rant, we close their question, and nobody wins.  They are needed to prevent chronic bad askers from continuing to suck up curation resources, beyond just the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Sorry, but the purpose of downvotes is already clear, but they are also clearly being abused.  And the people who are abusing them are not interested in being educated.   The problem of people complaining about downvotes is not relevant to my proposal.

Comment: Show examples of abuse, please.  I challenge that assertion.  If anything, new users are abusing the time of volunteers trying to keep the site clean, by refusing to meet site standards, recreating new accounts to bypass the question ban, and overall, just wasting the time of others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590331/getting-a-nullpointerexception-when-adding-to-array   This did not need 3 downvotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782392/how-to-modify-this-code-to-print-the-3-integers-in-order  - Has has this guy been back?  I doubt it!

Comment: ...You're complaining about *three* downvotes?  That's not abuse in *any* sense.  I thought you were complaining about 20+ downvotes, not a whole three.  I can see why it got a few, though; people are *tired* of users refusing to search for errors, and just dump their question.  It has pictures of code instead of actual code.  There's no MRE.  Those questions meet the tooltip handily; zero research went into it.  That's not abuse on the voter's part.  That *doesn't* warrant three downvotes?  I'd say it warrants *far* more.

Comment: Yes.  I am complaining about 3 downvotes!!!  You are actually advocating that multiple downvotes is a good thing.  You are one of the people who I have challenged to justify that position.

Comment: Well, then I suggest you realign your expectations; that's unreasonable.  You're saying people shouldn't judge content because it might hurt feelings, and I feel that's an untenable position.

Comment: "Has this guy been back? I doubt it!" - actually, yes, he has, and [his second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985731/css-background-image-and-some-divisions-dont-work) was much better received.

Comment: How do we reconcile the "vote as you see fit, no matter the score of a question" with what you're saying though, @Stephen? Cause, I can see your point (I don't agree to it, but I can see it). However, voting that way is exactly what the site says we should do...... it really points to a lack of alignment in expectations, guidance, and documentation :/

Comment: @F1Krazy - Only once.  I guess he must have given up asking questions.

Comment: I'm a *huge* proponent of personal responsibility, @Stephen.  That means I believe people need to own their actions, good *and* bad.  Sometimes, that means facing a hard truth that's unpleasant.  That helps you grow and become a better person.  While the impetus is unpleasant, I feel that attempting to soften that feedback does the poster a massive disservice, especially as that's never been the purpose of voting in the first place.  Beyond that...you still haven't said if you feel applying this barrier to upvotes would be reasonable.